# Node: how to export/require correctly? Cannot serve static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and have been looking at the similar code but can't figure out whats wrong with mine. I serve static files from my `server/app/index.js` file - do I have to require it in my `server/index.js` file where I only start my server?
PS. my middleware routes responsible for statically serving files from browser/public folder don't work unless I put them insight server/index.js so I am wondering what I did wrong.

**`server/app/index.js:`**

```js
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var path=require('path');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../browser')));

module.exports = app;
```

**`server/index.js`**

```js
'use strict'
var app =require('./app/index.js');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337;

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Server is listening');
})
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You might want to ensure that `console.log(path.join(__dirname, '../../public'))` in `app/index.js` logs the expected value

Comment: First of all why you want to split server code into two i.e., first getting static files and requiring into another ??? You can do both actions in one server code.Anyway my suggestion is, in server/index.js file require express module and assign express() to app varaible as u did in server/app/index.js.And change variable name for require('./app.index.js'); instead of giving it as app

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear about what doesn't work! When I add app.use() to serve my static files to my server/index.js file it all works, but when I leave app.use insight my server/app/index.js file, Im just getting a 'cannot get' so my static files are not being served, so I must have not properly exported/required something?

Comment: @ syed -I didn't want to initialize app in my server/index.js file-here I really just want to start the server and initialize it in the file where my middleware routes etc is- Im not sure if thats good practice but according to some tutorial I looked up it is, so I was doing that..